# Использование нескольких баз БД в Spring Boot

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, spring-boot

Вопрос такой: Как подключить несколько БД к Spring Boot?

Ситуация: У меня проект, в котором надо использовать две БД разом, PostgreSQL и MSSQL. И если одну базу я могу подключить без проблем, то как подключать несколько я не представляю. А все мануалы, которые я находил, либо неполные, либо устаревшие.

Проблема в том что я новичок, и многих вещей тупо не знаю или не замечаю. Из-за этого сложно найти нужную информацию.

Так что, если подскажете мануал, либо как это делать, буду очень рад. :)

Comment: Вот, кажется, нужный вам мануал: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Comment: Да, большое спасибо.)

Answer (score 1):

если используете Spring Data JPA, то будет полезна ссылка: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]